# Having trouble getting mega menu to work responsively

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm using Drupal 7 and bootrap theme, but I've tried other themes as well and I can't get it to work responsively.

What it does is drop down, but it doesn't scroll, having a hard time to troubleshoot with Chrome dev tool because of media queries.

Any idea what is causing this? Megamenu is supposed to be responsive out of the box?

URL is :

http://www.dev.wearelao.com

Answer (score 0):

No, that module doesn’t claim to provide responsive menus.

Quite the opposite, in fact; its mission is to provide you with the tools you need to build your *own* styles, which can of course be responsive if you desire:

> The module provides classes and ID's that allow for a full-range of styling customization, from more traditional (but multi-level) drop-downs to full width slide out menus.
>
> **A couple demo skins are supplied, but these are purely for instructional purpose to help get you started with theming your mega menu.** Currently, you should have an understanding of how Drupal overrides module CSS files and how to add CSS to themes, in order to provide your own styles in your particular theme.

So the module just gives you a framework to start from, you need to provide your own CSS.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks, so a major undertaking then...any  responsive mega menus that work out of the box for Drupal? Or could I disable it on small screen and reenable bootstrap native on smaller screens?

Comment: You might try TB_megamenu.. but I'm a bit biased cause I did the D8 version.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got this solved, here is the answer.

Enable Bootstrap menu in backend settings, then set it menu to display none, on ALL media queries.

The Megamenu will then feed from the native bootstrap that is enabled but non displayed, works perfectly.